# stacked bar graph from groupby and count

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this after a `groupby` and `count`operation:

`timestamp   status
2018-08-27  0         15
            1          5
            2         28
2018-08-28  0         20
            1         10
            2         58
...`

When I try and plot it using `df.plot.bar(stacked=True)` I get the following graph which is not correct. How can I actually plot my calculation as a stacked bar graph?

[image]

Comment: How working `df.unstack(fill_value=0).plot.bar(stacked=True)` ?

Comment: perfectly, how and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need reshape `Series` with `MultiIndex` by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) to `DataFrame`:

```
print (df.unstack(fill_value=0))
status       0   1   2
timestamp             
2018-08-27  15   5  28
2018-08-28  20  10  58

df.unstack(fill_value=0).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image: pic]